# Using TPM how do I use the SRK key to seal

Tags: c++, tpm

Building a class to encapsulate TPM functions.  The purpose of this class is to use the SRK key to seal and unseal an array.  I get to the part of the code to seal and I need to give it a key and I don't know how to tell it to use the SRK key:
So what do I use as the second parameter (hSRKey) for this call:
    result=Tspi_Data_Seal(hEncData,hSRKey,inv.size(),inv.data(),hPcrs);

```
std::vector<u8> CTpm::sealVector(std::vector<u8> inv)
{
    std::vector<u8> retVec;
    TSS_HOBJECT hPcrs;
    TSS_HOBJECT hEncData;
    TSS_HKEY hSRKey;
    //TSS_HOBJECT hPcrs;
    //memset(hPcrs,0,sizeof(TSS_HOBJECT));
    UINT32 ulPcrLen;
    BYTE rbgPcrValueX;
    BYTE* rbgPcrValue = &rbgPcrValueX;

    // create context
    result=Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext,TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_PCRS,0,&hPcrs);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to create context while getting FileKey. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // get current value for PCR 8
    result=Tspi_TPM_PcrRead(hTPM,8,&ulPcrLen,&rbgPcrValue);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to get Current value for PCR 8. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // set value of sealed PCR 8 to current value
    result=Tspi_PcrComposite_SetPcrValue(hPcrs,8,20,rbgPcrValue);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to set value for PCR 8. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // get current value for PCR 9
    result=Tspi_TPM_PcrRead(hTPM,9,&ulPcrLen,&rbgPcrValue);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to get Current value for PCR 9. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // set value of sealed PCR 9 to current value
    result=Tspi_PcrComposite_SetPcrValue(hPcrs,9,20,rbgPcrValue);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to set value for PCR 9. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // Create an data object for sealing
    result=Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext,TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_ENCDATA,TSS_ENCDATA_SEAL,&hEncData);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to create object for sealing. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));

    // sealing the key
    result=Tspi_Data_Seal(hEncData,hSRKey,inv.size(),inv.data(),hPcrs);
    if (result)
        myLog->error("Unable to seal. %s", Trspi_Error_String(result));


    return retVec;
}
```

I get the result error code of "Invalid Handle"

Comment: The SRK has the persistent handle 0x40000000

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll want to load the srk key, easiest way to do that is using

```
TSS_UUID SRK_UUID = TSS_UUID_SRK;
Tspi_Context_LoadKeyByUUID(hContext, TSS_PS_TYPE_SYSTEM, SRK_UUID, &hSRKey);
```

Making this call will load a key into the tpm and give you a handle with it, using TSS_UUID_SRK as the user id instead gets the SRK ready for use, and gives you its handle. Once you've done that if you intend to use it for data sealing you'll need to set your authorisation on it, if your using the well known secret then you'll want to do something like this

```
TSS_HPOLICY hOwnerPolicy;
BYTE wks[20] = TSS_WELL_KNOWN_SECRET;

Tspi_GetPolicyObject(hSRK, TSS_POLICY_USAGE, &hOwnerPolicy);
Tspi_Policy_SetSecret(hOwnerPolicy, TSS_SECRET_MODE_SHA1, 20, wks);
```

Im afraid that my knowledge of TSPI only really reaches this far, but you might also need to set the owner policy, use this to get it.

```
Tspi_Context_GetTpmObject(hContext, &hTPM);
Tspi_GetPolicyObject(hTPM, TSS_POLICY_USAGE, &hOwnerPolicy);
```

then call Tspi_Policy_SetSecret on it, and set the secret to your owner password for the TPM. 
(Im not sure this final step is neccesary, I've included it since without it I ran into authorisation errors.)

I found most of this out by reading the section on the TCG and the section of symmetric keys in A Practical Guide To Trusted Computing. It's by far the most helpfull source I've been able to find on Tspi, even if its not perfect.